# urlFetchApp.fetch() seems to be failing silently when attempting a JSON POST to Discord Webhook

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, discord, urlfetch

I'm attempting to post a message from a Google Apps Script to a discord server. 
Attempting to debug by using logs reveals that the script seems to fail at the key line

> var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

The logs are empty from that point, ('hi' never appears in the logs) leaving me stumped with how to proceed with error identification.

How can I discover why the call to UrlDetchApp.fetch() is apparently failing?

I have redacted the actual webhook url in the example below.

```
function postMessageToDiscord() {

  message = "Hello World!";

  Logger.log("trying to post message: " + message);
  var discordUrl = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/[id]/[token]';
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: false
  };
  Logger.log('params set');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);
  Logger.log('hi');
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

EDIT using console.log has allowed me to identify that I'm missing some scopes from my project, I have now added these and authorised the app by calling the function in an installed onEdit trigger direct from the script screen.

Comment: `muteHttpExceptions:false`

Comment: same outcome - have updated that line in the example above

Comment: Can you try using `console.log()` instead of `Logger`. Maybe the logs are delayed? Are your `id` and ``token`` urlencoded? Also, try creating a new script project with only this function and see whether the problem is the same?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, how about this modified ``params``? ``var params = {method: "POST",payload: {content: message},muteHttpExceptions: false}`` Or ``var params = {method: "POST",payload: JSON.stringify({content: message}),muteHttpExceptions: false,contentType: "application/json"}``